# Converting JavaRDD to DataFrame in Spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to process the LogFile. first i read the log file and split these file as per my requirement and saved each column into separate JavaRDD. Now i need to convert these JavaRDD's to DataFrames for future operations. This is the code what i tried so far:

```
         SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AuctionBid").setMaster("local");
         JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
         JavaRDD<String> diskfile = sc.textFile("/Users/karuturi/Downloads/log.txt");
         JavaRDD<String> urlrdd=diskfile.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split("\t")[0]));
         System.out.println(urlrdd.take(1));
         SQLContext sql = new SQLContext(sc);
```

and this is the way how i am trying to convert JavaRDD into DataFrame:

```
DataFrame fileDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(urlRDD, Model.class);
```

But the above line is not working.I confusing about Model.class.

can anyone suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Imports:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
```

Create a POJO class for URL. I'd recommend you to write for Log line which consists of url, date, time, method, target,.. etc as members

```
public static class Url implements Serializable {
  private String value;

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Create an RDD of Url objects from a text file

```
JavaRDD<Url> urlsRDD = spark.read()
  .textFile("/Users/karuturi/Downloads/log.txt")
  .javaRDD()
  .map(new Function<String, Url>() {
    @Override
    public Url call(String line) throws Exception {
      String[] parts = line.split("\\t");
      Url url = new Url();
      url.setValue(parts[0].replaceAll("[", ""));
      return url;
    }
  });
```

Create DataFrame from RDD

```
Dataset<Row> urlsDF = spark.createDataFrame(urlsRDD, Url.class);
```

[RDD to DataFrame - Spark 2.0](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds) 
[RDD to DataFrame - Spark 1.6](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds)

Comment: What about if I want to convert a `JavaRDD` with a `SparseVector` in it?

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like (I am converting on the fly from scala so excuse any typos):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = urlrdd.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
    @Override
    public Row call(String record) throws Exception {
        return RowFactory.create(record());
    }
}
// now you wish to create the target schema. This is basically a list of
// fields (each field would be a column) which you are adding to a StructType
List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField("url", DataTypes.StringType, true);
fields.add(field);
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

// now you can create the dataframe:
DataFrame df= sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
```

A couple additional notes:

- Why are you flatmaping when you are only taking the first element? You could have simply done:

  `JavaRDD<String> urlrdd=diskfile.flatMap(line -> line.split("\t")[0]);`
- I assume in real life you would want to remove the '[' from the url (you can easily do this in the map).
- If you are moving to spark 2.0 or later then instead of sqlContext you should be using spark session (spark).
- You can create a single dataframe with all columns. You can do this by adding all fields to the schema (i.e. instead of just doing a single add to the fields add all of them). Instead of using urlrdd, use diskfile and do the split inside the "public Row call" creation. This would be something like this:

  `JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = diskfile.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
      @override public Row call(String record) throws Exception {
          String[] recs = record.split("\t")
          return RowFactory.create(recs[0], recs[1], ...);
      }
  });`
- You can create it directly: Just use

  `sqlContext.read.option("sep","\t").csv.load(filename,schema)`

Answer (score 4):

Just flatmap your data according to 7 column table and use code snippet below

```
String[] columns = new String[7] {"clumn1","column2","column3","column4","column5","column6","column7"};
List<String> tableColumns = Arrays.asList(columns);

StrucType schema = createSchema(tableColumns);

    public StructType createSchema(List<String> tableColumns){

        List<StructField> fields  = new ArrayList<StructField>();
        for(String column : tableColumns){         

                fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField(column, DataTypes.StringType, true));            

        }
        return DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
    }

sqlContext.createDataFrame(urlRDD, schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly read the file using sqlContext directly

Use read method of sqlContext

For more info you can follow this link

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes

Or you can import the

```
import sqlContext.implicits.*;
```

Then use `toDF()` method on rdd to convert into dataframe.

Comment: import sqlContext.implicits._ command not supporting in spark java

Comment: Yeah sorry just saw this. The best alternative you have is to use sqlContext to read the file. Because converting rdd to dataframe uses reflection so to reduce extra computation use sqlContext to read the file.