# Using the Apache Spark RDD map method (Java API) to produce a non-columnar result

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

**Please note:** I *believe* I'm correct in trying to use the RDD `map` method here, but if there is another way to accomplish what I'm looking for, I'm all ears!

---

Brand new to Spark 2.4.x here, and using the **Java** (*not* Scala) API.

I'm trying to wrap my brain around the RDD `map(...)` method, specifically on `Datasets` and not restricted only to RDDs. The canonical example of its use from the [official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) is:

```
public class GetLength implements Function<String, Integer> {
  public Integer call(String s) { return s.length(); }
}

JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("data.txt");
JavaRDD<Integer> lineLengths = lines.map(new GetLength());
```

So it seems that, in this case, that after the `lines` RDD is created, it has a single column (whose name I'm unsure of) where each column value is a different line of the file, and that each row in the RDD represents a different line of the file as well. Meaning, `lines` is an `nx1` matrix where `n` is the number of rows/lines in the file.

It also seems that when the `GetLength` function is executed, it is fed each row's one-and-only column as the input string and returns an integer representing the line length of that string as a new column value in a different dataset, which is also `nx1` (just holding line length info instead of the actual lines/strings).

OK, so I get that trivial example. But what if we have `nxm` datasets, meaning, lots of rows and lots of columns, and we want to write functions that transform them into other `nxm` datasets?

For example, let's say I have the following "input" dataset:

```
+-------------------------+
| price | color | fizz    |
+-------------------------+
| 2.99  | red   | hallo   |
| 13.94 | blue  | yahtzee |
| 7.19  | red   | trueth  |
...
| 4.15  | green | whatevs |
+-------------------------+
```

Where `price` is a numeric/floating-point type and both `color` and `fizz` are strings. So here we have an `nx3` shaped dataset; `n` rows and always 3 columns in each row.

How would I write a map function that also returned an `nx3` dataset, with the same columns/column names/schema, but different values (based on the function)?

For instance, say I wanted a new `nx3` dataset with the same schema, but that added `2.0` to the `price` column if the row's `color` value equals the string `"red"`?

Hence, using the arbitrary dataset above, the new dataset coming out of this map function would look like:

```
+-------------------------+
| price | color | fizz    |
+-------------------------+
| 4.99  | red   | hallo   |  <== added 2.0 to price since color == "red"
| 13.94 | blue  | yahtzee |
| 9.19  | red   | trueth  |  <== added 2.0 to price since color == "red"
...
| 4.15  | green | whatevs |
+-------------------------+
```

I'm *tempted* to do something like:

```
public class UpdatedPriceForRedColors implements Function2<String, Double, Double> {
  public Double call(String color, Double currentPrice) {

    if ("red".equals(color) {
        return currentPrice + 2.0;
    } else {
        return currentPrice;
    }
  }
}

JavaRDD<Double> updatedPrices = myDS.map(new UpdatedPriceForRedColors());
```

However, several issues here:

1. `updatedPrices` is now only an `nx1` dataset consisting of the correctly-computed prices for each row in `myDS`, whereas I want something that has the same `price/color/fizz` that looks like the 2nd arbitrary dataset up above
2. How does the `UpdatedPriceForRedColors` know that its first string argument is the `color` column, and *not* the `fizz` column?
3. The Function API seems to only go up to either `Function5` or `Function6` (it's hard to discern what is available to the Java API and what is exclusive to the Scala API). This means I can only write functions that take in 5 or 6 arguments, whereas I might have datasets with 10+ columns in them, and I might very well need  most of those column values "injected" into the function so I can compute the return value of the new dataset. What options do I have available in this case?

Comment: Why the DV? This question is on topic, not a duplicate and shows reserch!

Comment: Reprexes are not a requirement of questions on SO, they are only an encouraged practice. I was not presenting the code snippet above as a reprex or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), as indicated by my comment "_I'm **tempted** to do something **like**..._".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, RDDs kind of always have one *column*, because RDDs have no schema information and thus you are tied to the `T` type in `RDD<T>`.

**Option 1** is to use a `Function<String,String>` which parses the `String` in `RDD<String>`, does the logic to manipulate the inner elements in the String, and returns an updated String.

If you want your `RDD` to have some schema information, you can use an `RDD<Row>` which lets you access separate elements inside a `Row` **(option 2)**.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
JavaRDD<Row> rddRow = rddString.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
    @Override
    public Row call(String line) throws Exception {
      String[] parts = line.split("\\t");//tab separated values
      Row row = RowFactory.create(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
      return row;
    }
  });
```

Now you can map the rows:

```
RDD<Row> updatedRdd = rddRow.map(new Function<Row, Row>() {
    @Override
    public Row call(Row row) throws Exception {
      Float price = row.get(0);
      String color = row.get(1);
      //Your logic here          
      Row row = RowFactory.create(/* three elements here, or whatever*/);
      return row;
    }
  });
```

If you go one step further, you can use a true Dataset (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302666/converting-javardd-to-dataframe-in-spark-java)) and leverage the Dataframe/Dataset API **(option 3)**.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(
    new StructField[]{
            DataTypes.createStructField("price", FloatType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("color", StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("fizz", StringType, false)
    });


JavaRDD<Row> rddRow = rddString.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
    @Override
    public Row call(String line) throws Exception {
      String[] parts = line.split("\\t");//tab separated values
      Row row = RowFactory.create(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
      return row;
    }
  });

DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
```

Having a dataframe lets you now use something like this:

```
DataFrame df2 = df.withColumn("price", 
    when(col("color").equals("red"), col("price").add(2f))
        .otherwise(col("price")));
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't checked the java syntax and API as I'm used to scala.*